# Change database schema used by Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How do I specify database schema used by Spring Boot? I am using default hibernate (=default) and postgres (but i hoping for a generic solution). I know how to specify JDBC URL:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql:db_name
```

But unfortunately postgresql does not allow to specify schema in JDBC URL. I know that there is hibernate property `hibernate.default_schema`, so I was hoping that one of the following properties will work:

```
hibernate.default_schema=schema
spring.hibernate.default_schema=schema
spring.jpa.hibernate.default_schema=raw_page
```

But unfortunately neither of them seems to have any result.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Use for `application.properties`:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=your_scheme
```

OR for `application.yaml`:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate.default_schema: your_scheme
```

From the Spring Boot reference guide:

> all properties in `spring.jpa.properties.*` are passed through as normal JPA properties (with the prefix stripped) when the local `EntityManagerFactory` is created

See http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-jpa-properties

For a full list of available properties see http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-jpa-properties

Comment: It seems that I missed this part in guide. I am not sure why ddl-auto is changed by `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` but schema is changed by  'spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema'. Still it works as described in guide, so thank!

Comment: The *spring.jpa.hibernate.x* vs *spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.x* is really confusing. The *spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.* worked for me.

Comment: pay attention that the schema name must be in lowercase

Comment: The full list of available properties is [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/devguide/en-US/html_single/#d5e4971).

Answer (score 29):

It depends on the DataSource implementation which property has to be used to set the default schema ([reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-configure-a-datasource)). With HikariDataSource for example `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema` is ignored and you have to set

```
spring.datasource.hikari.schema=schema
```

See the complete list of HikariCP configuration parameters [here](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby).

Comment: Indeed i had the ikari datasource set up and it would not get the schema through `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema` but it worked fine with the ikari way.

Comment: I cannot see why said JPA option would be 'ignored' if using Hikari as it works at the JDBC level and has no knowledge if JPA.

Setting `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema` means Hibernate will generate SQL with each object qualified by a schema name (unless already qualified explicitly). Therefore, it will be irrelevant to set a (default) schema name on the JDBC connection itself (i.e. via Hikari). You can say that the two are alternatives. Doing it via Hibernate is a lot better as not every database supports the notion of a default schema on a connection.

Comment: @peterh you're right, it's ugly to be forced to use connection pool specific properties, but as stated `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema` did not work. I do not think that a proper solution for Hibernate would be to prefix each object with the schema name - considering native queries.

Comment: @vboerchers. You got a point on native queries. The `hibernate.default_schema` only applies to SQL generated by Hibernate. After your comment I no longer know what is preferable. I guess it depends. :-)
On a plain vanilla Spring Boot application I still cannot replicate that use of Hikari would mean that `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema`  is ignored.

Comment: I swear that at some point, my application worked using hibernate.default_schema, and started ignoring this property when I migrate from SB 3.0.6 to SB 3.1.1.. Or was it when I introduced flyway to my project ? No idea, but that wasn't clear from the logs or documentation. Anyway, thanks for the information.

Answer (score 2):

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        default_schema: your_schema_name
```

Answer (score 1):

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=your_scheme

OR

spring:
jpa:
properties:
hibernate.default_schema: your_scheme

With **HikariDataSource** for example spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema is ignored and you have to set too

spring.datasource.hikari.schema=your_scheme

Comment: spring.datasource.hikari.schema=your_scheme, In my case this is also not working. I have added this in application.properties still hitting error.  PSQLException: ERROR: relation "result_details" does not exist
  Position: 16
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440)

Answer (score 1):

I was hitting error:
Cannot acquire connection from data source
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: unsupported startup parameter: search_path

Solution:
application-xyz_dev.yml

url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:8080/your_database?search_path=your_scheme&stringtype=unspecified

spring:
jpa:
properties:
hibernate.default_schema: your_scheme