# How to fetch schema name for a Spring data jpa entity from config

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

In my spring boot app, I am using spring data jpa. In the entity, I need to pick schema name from config and the schema would change and needs to be configurable. I tried the following but it doesn't work

```
@Entity
@Table(schema="${schema.name}", name="MyTable")
```

schema.name is define in application.properties file

I get "could not extract resultset" error

Is there a way to accomplish this ?

===============EDIT===============

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MyTable")
public class MyData {

    @Id
    @Column(name="MyID")
    @JsonProperty("MyID")
    private String MyID;

    @Column(name="number")
    @JsonProperty("number")
    private String number;

    @Column(name="value")
    @JsonProperty("value")
    private String value;

    ......getter and setters go here.....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=schema
```

You can see [this similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24278659/change-database-schema-used-by-spring-boot?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Answer (score 0):

Please set the schema and other DB related config in **application.properties** file. 
Its not good practice to keep schema name in Entity.

like below code:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.97.39:3309/schema-name?autoReconnect=true&autoReconnectForPool=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.datasource.username=userName
spring.datasource.password=Password
```

Here Schema name configured in `spring.datasource.url` property

Comment: I removed schema name from @Table and moved it to spring.datasource.url. Got following error now. Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Table [MyTable] contains logical column name [txnid] referring to multiple physical column names: [txnid], [txn_id].

Comment: Remive all the schema from all the entity

Comment: I have one entity only and removed schema named from that. The error explained above is a result of that.

Comment: as per the error message"DuplicateMappingException", the exception coming bacause of wrong mapping.
check '@ManytoOne', @'OneToMany' 0r '@ManyToMany'anontations or share the entity file

Comment: There aren't any associations . Just using one single table

Comment: can you please share that file

Comment: entity looks ok, i need to see some more thing, like Db table(MyTable), and repository code, properties file. if possible please share all the files with table