# Java Spring Data specifying schema

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Hi I have an entity which maps from view in particular schema.
Class definition:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "VIEW_NAME", schema = "MY_SCHEMA")
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {
}
```

If I specify schema right on my MyEntity class everything woks it fetches records from database, but i wan't it to be more flexible and configurable from properties. I tried adding property to my properties file:          `spring.datasource.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema: MY_SCHEMA`

It doesn't work when i try to fetch i get an exception:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not
>   exist

Did i used wrong property ? Is there another way to change schema dynamically on entity ?

Comment: Use `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema = MY_SCHEMA`

Comment: Here is the response : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24278772/4373948

Comment: It doesn't work I get exception: Property spring.datasource.schema with value 'ServletContext resource [/MY_SCHEMA]' is invalid: The specified resource does not exist. I think it's because my table is actually view.

Answer (score 7):

The property name is `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=<schema-name>`