# Multiple schema for SQL Server in Spring boot

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, schema

My schema names are different for Test and Prod environments. How to access them from properties file? I want to read the schema from the properties file based on the environment. Tried the link suggested by adding in datasource config but it is not working. The database is SQL server.

Comment: please mention your requirement clearly. Or please look at the below link once.                                          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24278659/change-database-schema-used-by-spring-boot/24278772

Comment: are you using gradle or maven"

Comment: i am using maven..

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a properties file for each profile (applications-test.properties and applications-prod.properties) and for each env you put your database configuration.

Make sure to use the right profile in your code.

Comment: where to give schema in configuration

Comment: For Hibernate as JPA provider use:

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=dbo

For plain JDBC, add it to your connection string:

jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase?currentSchema=myschema

Comment: okay, but for multiples schema how you'll provide.
Tried this in config file props.put("Spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema","schemaname") but it is not working

Comment: you want multiple schema because you have multiple env right ?
you want 1 schema per env ?

Comment: No i have multiple schemas in each environment

Comment: You can use multiple datasources

Comment: Currently am using mulitple datasources but where to specify schema name for it

Comment: you add schema just like I showed you, multiple datasources, 1 schema per datasource means multiple schema

Comment: Isn't this "Spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema" unique for properties file?

Comment: yes you use "Spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema" in a properties file

Comment: Then schema will be same for other datasources in properties file

Comment: yes exactly, 2 properties files, multiple datasources in each properties file means multiple schema for each env

Comment: what you are suggesting is
testschema1.props, 
 testschema2.props,
 prodschema1.props, 
 prodschema2.props ?