# Where can install the schema in project with hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, application.xml

I use hibernate. I need to set the current schema somewhere other than in the @Table annotation or in jdbc:postgresql://HOST:PORT/ in application.yml
Tell me where else you can install the schema?

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema: contact does not see the setting

Comment: It looks like like you are not only using Hibernate but also a SpringBoot. Could you confirm on that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24278659/change-database-schema-used-by-spring-boot

Comment: @Michal Yes, I using SpringBoot

Comment: @Sergei No. I tried to establish default_schema with help spring: jpa: properties: hibernate: default_schema , but the setting does not seem to be read and there is no reaction

Comment: The YML file is so easy to get wrong. Could you - just for the sake of the experiment- try to set the property in other way then via the application.yml? For example, passing it per -D switch at start? Also remove all the other settings, i.e. yml and @Table and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In application.yml

spring:
datasource:
hikari:
schema: nameSchema

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).